# Create a website with multiple languages and multiple domains and contents with react and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I want to develop a website with different languages and contents and host in different domains but same UI with Reactjs and Nodejs.

example:

`www.english.com` for English content and language.

`www.chinese.com` for Chinese content and language.

`www.japanese.com` for Japanese content and language.

Should I deploy the same project into all domains and connect it with different database?

What's your opinion?

Comment: for backend what are you planning to use?

Comment: I use express.js to send api then use fetch api in reactjs.

Comment: In terms of codebase for both UI(use i18n) and Backend you will have single repo only and for deployment, I feel it can differ from person to person based on your choice of architecture.

Comment: You can even have a single domain but serve based on location such that the specific language is only served, [AWS Route53 Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy-geo.html) i

Comment: I want to create a news website to upload articles in different country. If you're want to create a website in these concept. Which is your choice?

Comment: Once again it will depend on the business side whether you want to have different domains/sub-domains or just have same domain and serve based on `geo-location`. Also I would suggest to have a look at `headless-cms` solutions like `strapi` might save a lot of time